# Community wiki on climbing styles

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I've thrown up a community wiki to explain some climbing styles

[Bouldering vs aid climbing vs free climbing vs free solo climbing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/bouldering-vs-aid-climbing-vs-free-climbing-vs-free-solo-climbing)

Feedback appreciated?

Comment: Nice one mate. Not a climber and had zero clue on what bouldering meant :)

Answer (score 2):

Nice idea @Liam. I think it's good to tell that boulders are typically up to around 3 meter but in the comparison I would remove the "above 3m" part from the other types of climbing. It's not that important of an info and quite self-explaining. Also it may sound as if the border of that specific height *3m* is ultra important which is not the fact. I made an edit right now...

I would like to see some info on trad-climbing because I heard very different opinions about the definition. I understand it [as it is defined here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/4639/2653). I think we have some experts on that topic over here which hopefully clear things up.

Comment: The answer is community wiki, so you can make whatever edits you want to it.

Comment: @Shem I know but wanted to discuss it here because others may think we shouldn't remove the "3m part".

Comment: That's what rollbacks are for, just explain your edits and I'm sure most people won't have an issue with it.

Comment: @Shem so what is this thread here about?